# How to change the file extension of files that contain a certain string with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, rename-item-cmdlet

I'm trying to automatically rename all *.txt files to *.log files, but only if they contain the upper case string ERROR.

However, the following code doesn't work:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -file | Select-String "ERROR" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.txt','.log' }
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string.
```

I found out that I can get the actual path with:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -file | Select-String "ERROR" | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Path }
```

but I can't figure out how to use it with `Rename-Item`.

I also tried:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -file | Select-String "ERROR" | [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "log")
```

but I got the following error message:

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
Select-String -Path *.txt -List -CaseSensitive 'ERROR' |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.FileName -replace '\.txt$', '.log' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- Use `-CaseSensitive` to ensure case-sensitive matching.
- Use `-List` to stop searching after the first match in a given file has been found, as an optimization.
- Take advantage of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Path` parameter that directly accepts a wildcard pattern of files to look for - no need for a separate `Get-ChildItem` call in this case.
- Since it is the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances emitted by `Select-String` that provide the input to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) - via their `.Path` property - you must use their `.FileName` property to refer to the file name in the [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) passed to `-NewName`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where-Object` to filter the file system items based on what `Select-String` finds:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -file |Where-Object { $_ |Select-String "ERROR" -CaseSensitive } |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.txt','.log' }
```

Comment: How about `Where-Object { $_ -cmatch 'ERROR' }`?

Comment: @lit I interpreted OP's description of files "contain[ing] the upper case string ERROR" to mean _the contents_ need to contain the string, not just the file name

Comment: Yes, I interpreted it differently. I thought the file name needed to contain 'ERROR'.